# What is the word "funny" modifying in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs

> I don’t understand why Daniella is acting so funny.

Is *funny* modifiying Daniella (which would make it an adjective) or is it modifying *acting* (making it an adverb)?

Is there any way to tell from this sentence?

Comment: There's no way to tell. You can use either an adjective or an adverb in that position. And for this meaning, *"funny"* is both an adverb and an adjective, so you can parse it as either one. Consider [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=acting+so+crazy%2Cacting+so+crazily%2C+acting+so+strange%2C+acting+so+strangely&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cacting%20so%20crazy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cacting%20so%20strange%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cacting%20so%20strangely%3B%2Cc0) for *"acting so strange"* and *"acting so strangely"*.

Answer (score 1):

*funny* in this sentence is an adverb (meaning *strangely*) modifying the verb *acting*.

Comment: and it should be funnily

Comment: @Martin You seem to disagree with at least one major dictionary {[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/funny)}: **funny** adverb >> It doesn't even label the flat adverbial usage as 'informal', never mind 'slang'.